# Android handle swipe on parent view and click on child

Tags: android

I am following the google developer documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

I am doing the exact same case as their example code, where I have a swipe gesture on a parent, but if I am not swiping, then I will handle the click on the child as opposed to intercepting on the parent. 
However the current flow is like this:

```
       Action.DOWN - > Hits Parent's onInterceptTouchEvent I return false since I am not waiting for this case
       Action.DOWN - > Hits Child's onTouch Handler, I return false since I still want to possibly use the parents code
      Action.DOWN -> Hits Parents' onTouch Handler, I return true because i want to get the rest of the notifications for the gesture and then pass on to the child when appropriate. If I return false at this point, then the event will die and I wont get Action.UP
```

At this point in the gesture I am strictly relegated to the Parent's `onTouchListener` and feel pigeonholed there since there are conditions where I would like to go back down to the child's `onTouch` handler. Particularly confounding are the following stipulations in the Android documentation:

*The down event will be handled either by a child of this view group, or given to your own onTouchEvent() method to handle; this means you should implement onTouchEvent() to return true, so you will continue to see the rest of the gesture (instead of looking for a parent view to handle it). Also, by returning true from onTouchEvent(), you will not receive any following events in onInterceptTouchEvent() and all touch processing must happen in onTouchEvent() like normal.
For as long as you return false from this function, each following event (up to and including the final up) will be delivered first here and then to the target's onTouchEvent().*

So my desire is to get at least up until the point of `Action.MOVE` within the parent's `onInterceptTouchEvent` so that I can determine whether or not this gesture is the childs click/touch or the parent's swipe. I can only seem to get to `ACTION_UP` in my parent's `onTouchEvent` since I return `true` at `Action.DOWN` which relegates my entirely, as the documentation says, to my parents `onTouch` method.

How can i keep the `onInterceptTouchEvent` spinning while also implmenting the `onTouchEvent` never return `true` until the moment I want the parent to do something in lieu of the child?

That is my logical idea, but when I do that, I have to make my parent's `onTouch` return `false` for the `ActionDown` which then kills the event from both `onTouch` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` paradigms.

Parent's on touch listner:

```
 binding.linLayoutWrapper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        int downX, moveX, upX;
        int downY, moveY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //binding.linLayoutWrapper.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                downX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                downY = (int) motionEvent.getY();
                return false;
            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                return false;

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                moveY = (int) motionEvent.getY();
                moveX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                if (Math.abs(downX - moveX) > Math.abs(downY - moveY)){
                    upX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                    if (upX - downX > 100) {
                        // swipe right
                        CalendarDay cal = binding.calendarView.getCurrentDate();
                        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal1.setTime(cal.getDate());
                        cal1.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
                        binding.calendarView.setCurrentDate(cal1.getTime());
                        binding.linLayoutWrapper.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        return true;

                    } else if (downX - upX > 100) {
                        CalendarDay cal = binding.calendarView.getCurrentDate();
                        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal1.setTime(cal.getDate());
                        cal1.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
                        binding.calendarView.setCurrentDate(cal1.getTime());
                        binding.linLayoutWrapper.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        return true;

                    }


                } else {
                    binding.linLayoutWrapper.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Parents onInterceptTouchListener:

```
     @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("HELP", " in parent action up");
        mIsScrolling = false;
        return false;
    }

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mIsScrolling) {
                return true;
            }

            final int xDiff = calculateDistanceX(ev);

            if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                // Start scrolling!
                mIsScrolling = true;
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            xNot = ev.getX();
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally my child's onTouch listener:

```
         relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditAvailabilityActivity.class);
                        if (event != null) {
                            int nurseId = AccountManager.sharedManager().getCurrentAccount().getId();
                            Conflict conflict = new Conflict();
                            conflict.setNurseId(nurseId);
                            conflict.setId(event.getConflictId());
                            conflict.setEndDate(event.getParentEnd());
                            conflict.setStartDate(event.getParentStart());
                            conflict.setStartTime(event.getStartTime());
                            conflict.setEndTime(event.getEndTime());
                            conflict.setIsAllDay(event.getAllDay() == 1);
                            intent.putExtra(EditAvailabilityActivity.EXTRA_CONFLICT, Parcels.wrap(conflict));
                        }
                        intent.putExtra(EditAvailabilityActivity.EXTRA_MODE, true);
                        ((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

UPDATE:

If I return true from the child's `onTouchListener` then it goes to the parent's `onInterceptTouchEvent`. I am not sure how that jives with what android says when they say " *Also, by returning true from onTouchEvent(), you will not receive any following events in onInterceptTouchEvent() and all touch processing must happen in onTouchEvent() like normal.*" It seems like a flagrant contradiction, but maybe they mean "when you return true from the PARENT's onTouchListener" IS that accurate?

When I change my childs `onTouchListener` to this:

```
     relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditAvailabilityActivity.class);
                        if (event != null) {
                            int nurseId = AccountManager.sharedManager().getCurrentAccount().getId();
                            Conflict conflict = new Conflict();
                            conflict.setNurseId(nurseId);
                            conflict.setId(event.getConflictId());
                            conflict.setEndDate(event.getParentEnd());
                            conflict.setStartDate(event.getParentStart());
                            conflict.setStartTime(event.getStartTime());
                            conflict.setEndTime(event.getEndTime());
                            conflict.setIsAllDay(event.getAllDay() == 1);
                            intent.putExtra(EditAvailabilityActivity.EXTRA_CONFLICT, Parcels.wrap(conflict));
                        }
                        intent.putExtra(EditAvailabilityActivity.EXTRA_MODE, true);
                        ((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return true; //this makes it behave strangely
                }
            });
```

It effectively handles the click but it seems to do so in a weird way. It violates the android documentation by going back to the parent's `oninterceptTouchEvent` all the way through `Action_UP`. This seemed promising because if i could get that far along the gesture and still get the right outcome from the target's `onTouch` method then I would get what i was looking for. Sadly in this case, when I try to do a swipe gesture I only get the following rapartee between parent and child:

```
         Action.DOWN - > Parent's onInterceptTouchEvent
         Action.Down -> Hits Child's OnTouchListener which is returning "true"
         Action.Cancel -> Hits Parent's onInterceptTouchEvent
```

This is the expected flow, so it was wishful thinking that it work but it was not in line with the earlier contradiction I noticed.

Comment: Hello, Getting of the day, i have face same issued. please give me a solution for using child swipeview in listview.

Comment: Hi @mujjuraja I created a single Gesture recognizer which overrides onTouch. I pass this instance both to the parent as well as he children. I then see if the gesture is a swipe or a click by measuring the motionEvent.getX and motionEvent.getY. If it is not big enough of a left or right direction I programmatically call click on the target view, otherwise I call an interface method the parent implements to swipe in either direction . I hope this helps.